# What formula does SQL Server 2008 use in STDistance?

Tags: sql, distance

I am analyzing the accuracy of the STDistance function for geographical objects in SQL Server 2008, in order to understand its behaviour better I need to find the underlying formula.

Does anyone knows which formula is used in SQL Server, haversine?

Comment: may be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975066/net-equivalent-of-sql-server-stdistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft (due mostly to a lack of knowledge about geodesics) elected to
define geographical distances along great ellipses and this is what
STDistance on Geographic objects returns.  For the formulas that are
used see Kallay, Geometric algorithms on an ellipsoid earth model (2008),
http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1463434.1463487  Also relevant is Kallay, Defining edges on a round earth (2007), 
http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1341012.1341087 (be warned that this paper contains several misstatements about geodesics).