# Why is SQL Server 2019's STDistance Very Slightly Different Than The Vincenty Formula? (Same Up To ~0.0001km)

Tags: coordinate-system, sql-server, distance-matrix, geodesic, vincenty-formulae

I'm trying to make a C language equivalent to STDistance. Through research, I've narrowed down what STDistance uses, which apparently is the (inverse) Vincenty Formula. The problem is, I've tried comparing a few different pairs of lat-long points in STDistance and using the Vincenty Formula, on [here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html) and also using this Python code (with the lat/longs filled in):

```py
import geopy
from geopy.distance import geodesic

point1 = ()
point2 = ()

print(geodesic(point1, point2).km)
```

And also, I converted STDistance meters to kilometers by dividing the result by 1000. The thing is, once the results get past the 4th decimal point they seem to be completely different. I understand this is relatively negligible, but I'd like to figure out why this is happening. Is the problem related to floating-point errors that happen in SQL Server? Rounding? Or perhaps something else, like a bug?

Here's an example:

Using the two random lat-long points, (35.22229, -119.02138) and (38.148205, -121.0777), here are the results I get.

**SQL Server Code:**

```sql
DECLARE @g geography;  
DECLARE @h geography;  
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-119.02138 35.22229)', 4326);  
SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-121.0777 38.148205)', 4326);  
SELECT @g.STDistance(@h);
```

**Python Code:**

```py
import geopy
from geopy.distance import geodesic

point1 = (35.22229, -119.02138)
point2 = (38.148205, -121.0777)

print(geodesic(point1, point2).km)
```

Now, from SQL Server I get the result, 373073.004092576 (in meters), or in kilometers, 373.073004093. On the other hand, from Python, I get 373.07302837349175 (in kilometers). And then finally, from [here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html) (the inverse calculator) I get 373073.028 (in meters), or in kilometers, 373.073028.

Any idea what's happening with this?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact Microsoft database in use. This could be as simple as rounding due to integer storage of coordinates. The difference is literally a fingernail thickness over the distance between NY and Washington, DC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SQL Server's STDistance function does not compute geodesic distances. Its algorithm essentially generates straight lines in 3D, densifies them and maps them on the ellipsoid in a manner described more specifically as such:

> [...] we have chosen to parameterize the ellipsoid with a mapping
> from a three dimensional space (with the exception of the origin)
> which we call the *space of directions*. The mapping takes any nonzero
> vector (, , ) to the unique point (, , ) on the ellipsoid
> on which (, , ) is an outward pointing surface normal.

(From [Geometric algorithms on an ellipsoid earth model, by M. Kallay](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1463434.1463487))

According to Kallay, the computed edges are actually equivalent to great elliptic arcs, and the distances it yields are indeed much closer to great ellipse distances, and definitely aren't geodesics by the nature of the algorithm. Detail of this algorithm can be found in [Geometric algorithms on an ellipsoid earth model, by M. Kallay](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1463434.1463487). It seems that the [Microsoft SQL Server documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stdistance-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) recognizes that the values aren't quite equivalent to geodesics:

> Note
>
> STDistance() returns the shortest LineString between two geography
> types. This is a close approximate to the geodesic distance. The
> deviation of STDistance() on common earth models from the exact
> geodesic distance is no more than .25%. This avoids confusion over the
> subtle differences between length and distance in geodesic types.

That last enigmatic sentence refers to the fact that because SQL Server's geographic features' edges are being treated with the same mapping scheme I explained earlier, developers decided to apply the same algorithm to the STDistance function so that it always yielded the same value as an edge's length value. I don't know why they use such an algorithm, and don't treat their edges as geodesics, but [this related answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58797/82947), by Charles Karney, author of several reknown papers about geodesics, suggests that it might be due to a lack of knowledge on the subject.

For your example, according to Charles Karney's GeographicLib geodesic distance calculator, the distance should be 373073.02837349, and matches GeoPy and PostGIS's values. Tools using Vincenty's formula also yield a value close to this (373073.028 rounded to the nearest millimeter). Since it is a relatively short distance, the difference from STDistance is rather small (24 mm), but for longer distances, and depending on where you are on the ellipsoid, the difference can be much larger. For distances around 10,000 km, the difference can be several meters, and for near-antipodal points, several *kilometers*.

Take this example below, computed with Charles Karney's algorithm on [GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/cgi-bin/GeodSolve?type=I&input=0%2090%200%20-90.1&format=g&azi2=f&unroll=r&prec=6&radius=6378137&flattening=1%2F298.257223563&option=Submit), versus SQL Server's result (I did not use Vincenty's here because it is ill-suited for near antipodal points):

```
Start point : 0°N, 90°E
End point :   0°N, 90.1 W
```

SQL Server result :

```
DECLARE @g geography;  
DECLARE @h geography;  
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(90 0)', 4326);  
SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-90.1 0)', 4326);  
SELECT @g.STDistance(@h);

------------
20026376.2765101
```

GeographicLib result : 20003008.421509

Notice the **23.3 km** difference! SQL Server's computing scheme takes the edge along the Equator, but the true shortest geodesic actually passes in a polar region since it is shorter this way.

So in short, do not use SQL Server's STDistance as a reference for geodesic distances, since it is not what this algorithm calculates.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would you say that using the C version of the GeographicLib library would be a good option? Also, I'm trying to look into how altitude could be taken into account with these calculations. So Iet's say I have thousands of lat/long points in a database. My main goal is to be able to take one of those points, and find the (top 10 let's say) closest other points that can be found in the database. The thing is, a more hilly or mountaneous terrain the same "flat" distance away as another point that is flat is technically further away. Is there a way to take this into account?

Comment: My current idea is the following. Let's say I have two points, pointA and pointB, and their GeographicLib distance. If I could find a good inexpensive (or free if possible) database/model of altitudes of the entire globe in different coordinates, perhaps I could take the average altitude of a number of points within the path between pointA and pointB and add it onto the GeographicLib result. Basically, I'm thinking of getting some sort of average altitude gain/loss of the path between pointA and pointB. Thoughts? And would you happen to know of any models that could provide this information?

Comment: Yes, I believe the C imprementation of GeographicLib would be a great choice for geodesic computations. For altitudes though, this would complicate matters, geodesics are paths along the ellipsoid surface only, they do not take into account altitudes or hilly terrain, nor geoid undulations. You could try factoring in the terrain profile, but that would render the computation task much longer and complex.

Comment: I guess one way to do it would be to create a terrain profile of the path, using, say, SRTM data or some other DEM data, with sufficient resolution, then calculate the true 3D distance of all your profile segments, to get the actual "terrain" distance.

Answer (score 3):

Without having access to the source code of SQL Server it may be impossible to say. As a comparison, PostGIS ST_Distance query from the geography example of https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html modified to use your test points gives

```
SELECT ST_Distance(gg1, gg2) As spheroid_dist, ST_Distance(gg1, gg2, false) As sphere_dist
FROM (SELECT
    'SRID=4326;POINT(-119.02138 35.22229)'::geography as gg1,
    'SRID=4326;POINT(-121.0777 38.148205)'::geography as gg2
    ) As foo  ;

373073.02837349 373433.04866826
```

PostGIS is open source and you can check from the source code how the result is computed. Because the results from PostGIS (with the spheroid alternative) and geopy are equal to the last digit they may be using the same code.